# Creating a graph using plotly throwing exception in Jupyter notebook

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, plotly

When I am creating a map in jupyter notebook using plotly package,I am able to do so without any issues.However when I use the same code and upload it in Kaggle kernel,below is the error I am getting.

NewConnectionError: : Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='plot.ly', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /clientresp (Caused by NewConnectionError(': Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution',))

The line at which it throws an error is:

`py.iplot(fig,validate=False,filename='choropleth-map')`

Comment: Sadly I cannot help you directly, but I suggest adding a few more bits of formatting and sharing perhaps a minimal snippet, which reproduces your problem. Sometimes prior lines are at fault so it is usually helpful to have a short snippet reproducing the error if it's possible to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting this error because kernels currently don't have internet access. You can still generate [offline plotly plots](https://plot.ly/python/offline/).